# Short story where the economy is so bad that everybody has advanced degrees and no jobs

Tags: story-identification

I read this story well over twenty years ago, so I really don't remember too many details. I am 99% sure it was in an issue of F&SF Magazine, from the 50's I think. Moreover, I think it was the story related to the cover art.

The cover art for the issue depicted a scruffy looking bearded man with a black fedora looking to the side in fear. I think he had a couple of paper scrolls in his hands. He was at the bottom of the cover and you could only see his torso and above. I know he was set against a dark object of some sort (a judges bench?) and the overall background was yellow.

I don't remember much about the story, just that the narrator was bitter because you needed three PhDs in order to get ahead while he only had a couple of Masters and thus couldn't find a job. Because of that, he winds up taking some kind of shifty job doing something illegal. That's all I remember.

Edit: I've now checked every F&SF cover from the beginning through 1979 and I'm not seeing it. I thought it was F&SF but it might have been Analog or something else- like I said, it has been over twenty years. That said I would suspect that it was late 60's through the 70's on further reflection; stories from the 50's didn't have such a pessimistic and dour look at things usually (please don't fill the comments sections with arguments, I said usually) as opposed to how I remember this. Will look more later.

Comment: You read it over **twenty** years ago but it's from a **50s** magazine? I thought this was gonna be easy because I've got those old F&SFs, all of them up to 1965 and lots of later ones. But I can't find the cover with your worried guy in a black fedora. Maybe it's my bad eyesight. If you can find the issue with the [cover picture](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?137044) you're talking about, I'll see if I've got it and check out the stories for you.

Comment: You could pick up a modern non-fiction article about most of North Africa (and perhaps even Spain) and read the same story.

Comment: Story? That's pretty much the description of modern Western society :-)

Comment: Part of the reason for my wanting to re-read the story is that it stuck with me all these years, how remarkably predictive it was.